# X% of users who visited Y page during a session triggered Z event

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up event tracking for a project I'm working on. I'd like to know what percentage of users who visit a certain page of the site trigger an event (say, clicking a button).

I've spent a few hours with Custom Reports and Calculated Metrics but I can't seem to get the right mix. I'm also new to Google Analytics, so still wrapping my head around the difference between pageviews, unique pageviews, sessions and users. As for how this looks in the end, the ideal would be:

```
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
|  Page  | Event action | Unique pviews with event / Total unique pviews |
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| /games | clickButton  | 3.45%                                          |
| /games | toggleNav    | 2.49%                                          |
| /team1 | clickButton  | 6.89%                                          |
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

And then I'd filter by page or event. Maybe event have drilldowns for Event Label. But open to any solution if drilldowns or some other sort of admin filtering makes this possible.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution yet?